# How to get files from specific folder in dropbox

Tags: android, dropbox

I am able to get all the FOLDERS from a specific path from dropbox. But now i want to get all the files from any specific FOLDER. Like if there is a FOLDER named "MyFolder1" in dropbox, now i want to get all the files from this FOLDER. So, how can i can accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1):

```
private boolean downloadDropboxFile(String dbPath, File localFile) throws IOException{

        BufferedInputStream br = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bw = null;

        try {
            if (!localFile.exists()) {
                localFile.createNewFile(); //otherwise dropbox client will fail silently
            }

            FileDownload fd = api.getFileStream("dropbox", dbPath, null);
            br = new BufferedInputStream(fd.is);
            bw = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(localFile));

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int read;
            while (true) {
            read = br.read(buffer);
            if (read <= 0) {
            break;
            }
            bw.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        } finally {
            //in finally block:
            if (bw != null) {
                bw.close();
            }
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Source: http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=23189&replies=5#post-159521

Answer (score 0):

I got solution by myself.

```
    String mPath="/";  //You can change the path here to specific FOLDER
Entry dirent = null;
 try 
   {
      dirent = mApi.metadata(mPath, 1000, null, true, null);            
    } 
 catch (DropboxException e)
   {
     System.out.println("Error Detail "+e.getMessage());
   }
```

> //Perform a Loop and retrieve all FILES and FOLDER from the PATH

```
     for (Entry ent: dirent.contents)
     {
       String name = ent.fileName();                           
       System.out.println("My File in Folder "+name);                        
      }
```